# Two (node:63440) Deprecation Warnings at the same time: current URL string parser and current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine are deprecated

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Anyone knows the way around both of these two deprecation warnings:

```
   (node:63440) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and wi
    ll be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUr
    lParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
    (node:63440) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
    is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Di
    scover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the Mo
    ngoClient constructor.
```

the code that gave the error was like this at first:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB');
```

but when I try to fix it by passing {userNewUrlParser: true} it works for the first deprecation but the second deprecation remains and if I pass all the two the code breaks completely
I tried:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

and that fixed the first deprecation, I also tried

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB', { useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

and that fixed the second deprication but I don't know how to fix both the two in my case I tried

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB', { useNewUrlParser: true },{ useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

and that completely ruined my app
I installed mongodb version v4.2.5 on the pc and the dependencies on the package.json are as follows:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the fix around multiple deprecations at once on Mongoclient and that is to use
the mongoose.set('whatever', true);
as for the issue I raised before the fix is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB');
```

The first line fill fix the first error and the second line will fix the second error

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB",{ 
    useNewUrlParser: true ,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

TRY this out!!!!

Comment: I think this is even better